# angular calling controller function in from directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a question that should be really simple, but i cannot find the answer.

I have controller a:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope){

    $scope.MyParentFunction = function(){ 

              alert("it does not work..");

    };     

}
```

And Controller b, which is inside a directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {

var directive = {};

    //properties
    directive.scope = {
        date: '=ngModel',
    },

    //controller
    directive.controller = function ($scope) {

        $scope.CallParentFunction = function(){

          //Call Function From Parent scope here
          $scope.MyParentFunction();     

        }

    },

    //call parent function in template
    directive.template = '<div ng-click="CallParentFunction()">Call</div>'; 

    return directive;

});
```

How can i call "MyParentFunction()" from my directive controller?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is `MyDirective` inside `myController` in the dom structure ? could you create a plunker as well, http://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: the following one is not working, but shows the main idea! http://plnkr.co/edit/dv90rBhtgXl9pOU12VKj?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help:

All you need is to bind your parent function

```
directive.scope = {
    date: '=ngModel',
    callParentFunction: "&"  //function binding 
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/y7I1g7bKok8NOADipqX4?p=preview

Take a look at the angularjs documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Yep, does the job pretty much! thanks. I knew it would be simple.